# How to Return multiple columns, but remove duplicates of 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, distinct

I'm trying to write a query to return all columns, and filter by displaying DISTINCT records from a specific column.

Here is my Query right now, which requires me to "Group By" everything in the select statement.  I obviously don't want to do this.:

```
SELECT     lVisitID, sFirstName, sLastName, sAddress1, sStoreNumber
FROM        Customers
WHERE     (dtServiceDate < '5/1/15') AND (sStoreNumber = '123') 
GROUP BY sAddress1
```

I've also tried the below, but that returns duplicates:

```
    SELECT     lVisitID, MAX(sAddress1)
    FROM        Customers
    WHERE     (dtServiceDate < '5/1/15') AND (sStoreNumber = '123') 
    GROUP BY sAddress1, lvisitID
```

Here is my data:

```
lVisitID     sFirstName   sLastName     sAddress1     sStoreNumber
  1             Bob          Jones         14 Place     123
  2             Jim          Bibby         12 Place     123
  3             John         Smith         12 Place     123
  4             Jen         Jones          22 Place     193
  6             Kim         Smith          15 Place     123
```

The idea here would be to return Only distinct addresses, and the store number.  When I attempt the above, I need:

```
  1             Bob          Jones         14 Place     123
  2             Jim          Bibby         12 Place     123
  6             Kim         Smith          15 Place     123
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want just the address that has the most recent visit, use `row_number()`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by address order by lVisitId desc) as seqnum
      from customers c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on Postgres SQL.

```
SELECT     Distinct on (sAddress1) *
FROM        Customers
WHERE     (dtServiceDate < '5/1/15') AND (sStoreNumber = '123')
```